# Remove SQL column in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I made this code to delete a column in laravel but the delete () command; Throw me
"Call to a member function delete () on string"

This is the code that results in this string from the sql

```
    //se elimina correctamente restaurant_user
    $restid = json_encode(DB::table('restaurant_user')->where('restaurant_id', $id)->first());
    //$restid = json_encode($restid);
    //echo "<script>console.log('Con Foreach transactions: " . $restid . "' );</script>";
    if ($restid) {
    $items = $restid;
    //echo "<script>console.log('Tienen que salir todas las variaciones: " . $items . "' );</script>";  
    foreach ((array) $items as $item) {
    echo "<script>console.log('Con Foreach transactions: " . $item . "' );</script>";           
    $item->delete();
    }   
    } else {
    return redirect()->route('admin.restaurants')->with(['message' => 'Algo salio mal en Restaurant_User']);
    }
```

The $restid varaible throws me this result:

`{"id":12,"user_id":4,"restaurant_id":12,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}`

For some reason I can't delete it

Comment: Well, your item variable comes from a json string, so the error message does make sense.

Comment: You are calling delete() on a string. Why are you using json_encode? Why the foreach if you  have ->first() on your query?

Comment: And you can't "delete" a column this way. If you're trying to empty out all of the values, then do it by setting the column to null or an empty string. Delete is to delete a whole record in the database.

Comment: can't you just do it by phpmyadmin?